# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: oracle11g

```
select  s.sname, count(*)
from    suppliers s, parts p, catalog c
where   p.pid = c.pid and c.sid = s.sid
group by s.sname, s.sid
having every (p.color = 'green')

select s.sname, max(c.cost)
from    suppliers s, parts p, catalog c
where   p.pid = c.pid and c.sid = s.sid
group by s.sname, s.sid
having some (p.color = 'green') and some (p.color = 'red')
```

when I am executing the above two queries it is showing missing right parenthesis.

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question and include a [mcve].

Comment: You need to terminate each statement with `;`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't support HAVING `EVERY` or `SOME`

you can handle it with `case when` statement on having clause.

Comment: can you please edit both the queries and post it for me thanks